# php global trim $_post

Tags: php

Could you trim all $_POST vars? because i have a very long list right now for trim each var. looks very unprofessional.  i thought trim($_POST); would maybe work but it didnt :]

Comment: It is worth noting that you really should set up a new array of the trimmed values, rather than editing global variables.

Answer (score 26):

you can do this with [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);
```

Comment: Right, like it even more than my own (and vote for it), wish it could do it in-place without assigning the array.

Comment: I do not recommend using this, as it shows an error if your $_POST contains an array (e.g. checkboxes). See valdas.mistolis's answer below.

Answer (score 23):

Works with multi-dimensional arrays

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST, function (&$val) 
{ 
    $val = trim($val); 
});
```

Comment: Since many forms contain checkboxes, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
foreach($_POST as &$p) $p = trim($p);
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick and simple:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    $_POST[$key] = trim($val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, and cleanest (in my opinion), is to use the built in [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map) function:

```
array_map('trim', $_POST);
```

You can also apply a method of your own by passing an array as the first callback-parameter like so:

```
array_map(array('My_Class', 'staticMethod'), $_POST); // Invoke a static method

array_map(array($myObject, 'objectMethod'), $_POST); 
// Invoke $myObject->objectMethod for each element of $_POST
```

**Update based on a comment below**

Sometimes the $_POST array may contain arrays. If you want to trim contents of those arrays as well, there are many custom implementations of `array_map_recursive` available in the [PHP manual user notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#113051). Go there and choose one for yourself. If you don't like to take a custom implementation, `array_walk_recursive` is also a good option for you.

Comment: @inakiabt: No, but there is a custom implementation of array_map_recursive in the PHP manual user notes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/array_walk).

Comment: The callback function for `array_walk` takes two parameters, one for the value and one for the key. But the second parameter of `trim` is intended for a list of character that should be removed from the begin and end. So it wouldn’t work. But with `array_map` it would.

Comment: It you wrote a simple wrapper for trim, array_walk would work in place.
 function aw_trim(&$str){
  if(is_string($str)){
   $str = trim($str);
  }
 }
        array_walk($_POST,'aw_trim');

Answer (score 0):

Using `recursive` function you can do that.

**PHP**

```
// Static $_POST Array.
$_POST['1']='one ';
$_POST['2']=' two';
$_POST['3'][]=' three   ';
$_POST['4'][][]=' four';
$_POST['5'][0][1][3]='five ';

// Recursive function for trim data.
function trim_recursive($array){
    $return = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$values){
        if(is_array($values)===true){
            $return[$key] = trim_recursive($values);
        }
        else{
            $return[$key] = trim($values);
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

// Usage.
$_POST = trim_recursive($_POST);
```

**Output**

```
// Output before trim.
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  string(4) "one "
  [2]=>
  string(4) " two"
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) " three   "
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) " four"
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        [3]=>
        string(5) "five "
      }
    }
  }
}

// Output after trim.
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "three"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "four"
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        [3]=>
        string(4) "five"
      }
    }
  }
}
```