# missing array $_POST when used $_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);

Tags: php, trim

i have check box named `check_user_id[]` like:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="87" name="check_user_id[]" class="waiting_user">
<input type="checkbox" value="88" name="check_user_id[]" class="waiting_user">
<input type="checkbox" value="89" name="check_user_id[]" class="waiting_user">
```

before page load i use this for trim

```
$_POST    = array_map('trim', $_POST);
```

all valus are getting but not `$_POST['check_user_id']` the value is directly get on its variable name `$check_user_id` b'coz my `register_globals` is `ON` but i just want to value in `$_POST['check_user_id']`

any way to do that ?

Comment: If you apply a string function to an array, the array will be gone. Use `array_walk_recursive()` instead of `array_map` to avoid that.

Comment: this isn't an SMS, you have free and unlimited characters. Downvoted... B'COZ i can.

Comment: Here it's the fourth answer: [php global trim $\_post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1336257) (possible duplicate)

Comment: @STTLCU i know that it's not sms

Comment: -1 B'coz of not using search.

Comment: if `register_globals` is on, you should turn it off as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

`trim` is function that works only on `strings`.

`$_POST` is an array and can contain only `strings` and **`arrays`**.

If you want to trim all strings in your multidimensional array, you should use or write some recursive function.

Or perform trimming manually on each element of your array:

```
foreach($_POST['check_user_id'] as &$check){
  $check = trim($check) ;
}
```

Comment: @mario Yes, I know, but I don't see any reason of performing `trim` operation on `$_POST` array. That would be a real overhead, as I can input a lot of useless data via `POST`.